# Implementing the Golden Section Rule

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization

I am attempting to write a code which brackets the minimum of a unimodal function,  using the Golden Section Method Below. I am have serious issues debugging my program though, any help will be appreciated.

```
(* Golden Ratio Search Method*)

GoldenSearch[a0_, b0_, ϵ_] :=
  Module[{a = N[a0], b = N[b0], bleft, bright, ρ, x1, x2},
   ρ = 
    N[Abs[(3 - Sqrt[5])/2] , 6];(*evaluates value of golden ration*)
   bleft = N[a, 6];(*left boundary point*) 
   bright = N[b, 6]; (*right boundary point*)

   x1 = N[bleft + ρ*(bright - bleft), 
     6];(*possible new left value*)
   x2 = N[bleft + (1 - ρ) (bright - bleft), 
     6];(*possible new right value*)


   While[ (b - a) > ϵ, If[ f[x2] > f[x1],
     Module[{},
      bright = x2;
      b = x2;
      x2 = x1;
      (*bleft = bleft*)
      x1 = bleft + ρ*(bright - bleft);],
     Module[{},
        bleft = x1;
        a = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        (*bright=bright*)
        x2 = bleft + (1 - ρ) (bright - bleft);
        ;], ;];
    Print["f[", PaddedForm[{a, x1, x2, b}, {7, 6}] "]", ;];];

   ];
```

An example function is:

```
f[x_] := x^2 + 4*Cos[x]; [1,2,0.2]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: I fully support what @MichaelE2 said, but I don't see a question being asked here. Are you asking the community to inspect your code, familiarize itself with the topic you are interested in and proceed to solve the problem ? It is best if you can narrow down the problem to a minimum and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: What is the bad behavior? What behavior are you expecting? What is the result you intend to return (if any)?

Comment: One thing to check out is the meaning of [`;;`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html) that appears near the end of the code.

Comment: I'm looking to find an interval to bracket a minimum point of a unimodal function, since posting this message I've figure the logic to implement in the loop, but I'm not sure how to apply it in mathematica. If I can output both endpoints and both middle points of each iteration, that would be great

Comment: Here is my new code:

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80508/revision-of-mathematica-coding-for-the-golden-search-method

Comment: @RufusMitchell Please, format your question - head to the help centre and read about code formatting.

Comment: Please pay attention to how to format your posts.  You should also edit the question itself to clarify the problem (instead of just in the comments).  Providing an example function `f` might be helpful, too, whether it is simple or complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the help in question revision

Comment: The code is much more readable now.  What problems are you having with it?

Comment: I cannot get the program to compile, @bbgodfrey, maybe a syntax issue

Comment: Part of the problem is with `Print`, which should be rewritten as, for instance, `Print["f[", ToString[PaddedForm[{a, x1, x2, b}, {7, 6}]], "]"] `.  I also deleted the second and third `Module` statements, which cause problems and seem unnecessary.  With these changes and the sample input provided, the code produces `f[{ 1.854102,  1.909830,  1.944272,  2.000000}]`.  If the hold is removed from your question, I shall provide an actual answer.

Comment: Sir @bbgodfrey the help is much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `Print` statement requires that the output from `PaddedForm` be converted to a String.  Additionally, the second and third Module statements cause problems and seem unnecessary.  With them deleted, the second half of the code can be rewritten as

```
 While[ (b - a) > ϵ, If[ f[x2] > f[x1],
       bright = x2; b = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = bleft + ρ*(bright - bleft),
        bleft = x1; a = x1; x1 = x2; x2 = bleft + (1 - ρ) (bright - bleft) ]];

 Print["f[", ToString[PaddedForm[{a, x1, x2, b}, {7, 6}]], "]"] ]
```

Then, with `f[x_] := x^2 + 4*Cos[x]` as suggested in the Question, `GoldenSearch` produces results.

```
GoldenSearch[1, 2, .2]
f[{ 1.854102,  1.909830,  1.944272,  2.000000}]
```